# What does "return;" mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Ran over this code:

```js
if(!function1()) return;
function2();
function3(array1[index1]);
```

What does having an instant semicolon after return mean? I found it under a jquery code. jquery has nothing to do with it right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `return` statement in Javascript terminates a function. This code basically says that if `!function1()` (the opposite of `function1()`'s return value) is `true` or truthy, then just stop executing the funciton.

Which is to say, terminate this function immediately. The semicolon is a statement terminator in javascript. If `!function1()` ends up being `true` or truthy, then the function will return and none of the code below it will be executed.

Return can be used to return a value from a function, like:

```
function returnFive(){
   return 5;
}
```

Or, like in this case, it's an easy way to stop a function if--for some reason--we no longer need to continue. Like:

```
function isEven(number){
  /* If the input isn't a number, just return false immediately */
  if(typeof number !== 'number') return false;
   /* then you can do even/odd checking here */
}
```

As you suspected, this has nothing to do specifically with jQuery. The semicolon is there so that the Javascript engine knows that there are two statements:

```
if(!function1()) return;
        function2();
```

Not just one statement, which you can see would totally change the program:

```
if(!function1()) return function2();
```