# What's the difference between document.write and the return statement?

Tags: javascript, return, document.write

So I wrote a function that generates 10 random numbers between 1 and 6, and I want to display the numbers on my HTML page, this is the Number Generate function :

```
function genereChiffre(){

var sResultat = "";
var iCompteur;
for(var i=0 ;i< 10 ;i++){ 

    sResultat = Math.round(Math.random()* 6) + 1;
     document.write("<li>" + sResultat + "</li>");

}}
```

This is the function to display the numbers :

```
(function (){

            var aLesDiv = document.querySelectorAll("#global div");

            aLesDiv[3].innerHTML = genereChiffre();    
        }) ();
```

What I don't understand is that when I use the document.write method and call the function as : genereChiffre() in the console, the 10 numbers are generated, but when I use a return statement as so

```
  return("<li>" + sResultat + "</li>");
```

It only generates 1 number.

Comment: the for which is inside stp to generate li

Comment: Please see this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/29290571/4275882.  It explains how `return` works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "return;" mean in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290539/what-does-return-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function genereChiffre(){

v

ar sResultat = "";
var _res
    var iCompteur;
    for(var i=0 ;i< 10 ;i++){ 


         sResultat += "<li>" + Math.round(Math.random()* 6) + 1 + "</li>"

    }
    return(sResultat); 
    }
```

Because , you are stoping the for, when you are calling "return", now return the sum of all count from the for

Comment: This will not do what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @KyleMartin., he asked why using return, gives only one number?

Comment: Yes, but your code will not return 10 numbers.  It will still only return 1.  The question itself really isn't that great, since he doesn't seem to actually have a problem he wants solved.

Comment: @KyleMartin, edited, and now, i belive hi put one li from 1 number, and will this the reason