# What does executing return; by itself do in this function, line 52?

Tags: javascript, recursion

[what does return; on line 52 work instead of break;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7niMh.png)

We've been working on this problem for a while now and was given a tip to use return; on line 52, initially we wrote "return solutionCount;"

Comment: Don't post code as images

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "return;" mean in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290539/what-does-return-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: The return by itself is not the mysterious part here. The mysterious part is why return anything at all when you completely throw away the returned value? Hint: `recursiveFunc(...)` instead of `return recursiveFunc(...)`

Comment: It's better to have the same return type even if JS is generous on that point. Your recursive helper seems to only return booleans so why not return `false` and get rid of the ridiculous `!!checkOutcome` that is just a funny way to cast values to booleans.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer: Remove the break argument its only used in `switch` statements and `loops`**

According to the [MDN Docs on return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.

When we do `return;` without passing anything else we are returning `undefined`. This will break out of the function without running the code underneath.

For your example after `solutionCount` is incremented it will break out of the `recursive` function without running the for loop.

Comment: In the OP's code you cannot use [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) since you are not in a `switch` or `label` statement.

Answer (score 0):

@jb151 the usage of `return;` is just a way to end the current function execution by returning (nothing, nil, null, undefined) and skipping the rest of the function instructions. Indeed if you capture in a variable the result value of a function that ends with `return;` you will get `undefined` as value.